# Will inserted and deleted record count always be equal in an update trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an update trigger with the following code:

```
declare @numrows  int       
select @numrows = @@rowcount

if @numrows <> 1
    return
```

In some cases @numrows returns 0 even though row count is 1. I think it's because the select resets the row count? Anyway, I'm replacing it with this:

```
set @numrows  = (select count(*) from inserted)
```

Later in the trigger I'm using both inserted and deleted table records. Will the row counts for inserted and deleted always be equal, or do I need to check them separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant comment on MERGE as Steve has in his answer, but if an UPDATE is run on a table

```
UPDATE TableA SET Column1 = "ABC" WHERE Column1 = "DEF"
```

And an update trigger exists on TableA, then when the trigger fires, yes, the count of records in each of the Inserted & the Deleted tables will be the same, and will be equal to the number of rows affected by the update statement that was run.

Answer (score 1):

*They will not be equal. Remember there are nice features like MERGE that can INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE all in one transaction which would make a single call to your trigger.*

**EDIT:**

After doing some more testing, my understanding of how MERGE worked is WRONG. They will be separate trigger events. One for each action INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

Therefore, I cannot think any reason that equal counts for INSERTED and DELETED would not mean they are all updates. More important, if you have any number of records in both tables, it is an update. Therefore this would be the fastest way for you to determine if it is an update:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM inserted) AND EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM deleted)
```

I am glad that merge does not work the way I thought because my triggers (which use the code above) would have failed.

Comment: I understand that merge could cause multiple triggers to fire and mess up @@rowcount. But wouldn't the inserted and deleted tables for the MERGE UPDATE still follow the same rules as a regular UPDATE?

Comment: If I have a MERGE that results in 1 insert and 1 delete (not an update) the trigger will be called once, with 1 INSERTED and 1 DELETED.

Comment: Hummm, not according the MSDN. I will have to test again!

Comment: @Sprockincat, I have edited my answer based on further testing.